# Customizing Bootstrap SASS variables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

I need to reduce the font-size of Bootstrap's Jumbotron header in Rails.
I see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#jumbotron)

that I need to add something like

```
@jumbotron-heading-font-size: ceil((@font-size-base * 2.5));
```

in my file

```
app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_customization.css.scss
```

So I changed "@" to "$", please see below how the file looks now:

```
$jumbotron-heading-font-size: ceil(($font-size-base * 2.5));
$jumbotron-padding: 20px;
@import "bootstrap";
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Do you use less or sass? Less - @var, sass - $var.

Comment: sass, but it looks like the issue is in the difference of syntax, not just $var or @var

Comment: can you post your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` file?

Comment: You should override bootstrap variables **after** you import them to your project. It's hard to say something more without your scss code.

Comment: just posted the content of the file app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_customization.css.scss

Comment: I didn't make any changes to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

Comment: this line: $jumbotron-padding: 20px;    is also before @import bootstrap, but it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.
As I'm using Bootstrap 4, I had a look at

```
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss
```

and found $display3-size variable there (this is a class for h1 tag inside Jumbotrone), so then I added the following line before @import bootstrap into my .scss file:

```
$display3-size: 2.5rem;
```

So it works now